# Failed to compile Java code to DEX in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build an android project in Unity and I receive this error:

```
Failed to compile Java code to DEX:
C:\Users\tziuka-pc\Desktop\project teo\Temp/StagingArea> java -Xmx1024M -Djava.ext.dirs="C:/Users/tziuka-pc/Desktop/dev2/android-sdk-windows\platform-tools/lib/" -jar "C:/Users/tziuka-pc/Desktop/dev2/android-sdk-windows\platform-tools/lib/dx.jar" --dex --verbose --output=bin/classes.dex bin/classes.jar plugins
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:/Users/tziuka-pc/Desktop/dev2/android-sdk-windows\platform-tools/lib/dx.jar

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
PostProcessAndroidPlayer:BuildDex(String, String) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/14194e8ce88cdf47/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostProcessAndroidPlayer.cs:634)
PostProcessAndroidPlayer:PostProcess(BuildTarget, String, String, String, String, String, String, BuildOptions) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/14194e8ce88cdf47/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostProcessAndroidPlayer.cs:249)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

I also use one plugin for Admob. When I delete this plugin, everything goes well. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [per the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/TroubleShooting.html#AndroidTroubleShooting), that is most likely caused by an outdated version of Java. Try updating your Java installation.

> **Building DEX Failed**
>   This is an error which will produce a message similar to the following:-
>
> ```
> Building DEX Failed! G:\Unity\JavaPluginSample\Temp/StagingArea> java
> -Xmx1024M -Djava.ext.dirs="G:/AndroidSDK/android-sdk_r09-windows\platform-tools/lib/"
> -jar "G:/AndroidSDK/android-sdk_r09-windows\platform-tools/lib/dx.jar" 
> --dex --verbose --output=bin/classes.dex bin/classes.jar plugins Error occurred 
> during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space
> for object heap Could not create the Java virtual machine. This is
> usually caused by having the wrong version of Java installed on your
> machine. Updating your Java installation to the latest version will
> generally solve this issue.
> ```

Comment: my java is updated...to the last version but unity isn't. Can be that a problem?

Comment: I would not necessarily expect it to be. But it won't hurt to try.